# Error occurred when loading a custom Julia module

Tags: module, julia

I have been puzzled by how to define and use custom `module` in Julia.

For example, I defined a `module` named `myMoldule` to wrap a mutable struct `Param` and a function `add` in `D:\\run\\defineModule.jl`:

```
module myMoldule

    export Param, add

    mutable struct Param
        x ::Int64
        y ::Int64
    end

    function add(x::Int64, y::Int64)
        sum ::Int64
        sum = x + y
        return sum
    end
end
```

and used this module in `D:\\run\\useModule.jl` like:

```
include("D:\\run\\defineModule.jl")
using .myMoldule

function testModule()
    param = Param(1, 2)
    sum   = add(param.x, param.y)
    println(sum)
end
```

An error occurred when running `testModule()` as follows:

```
julia> testModule()
ERROR: UndefVarError: Param not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] testModule() at D:\run\useModule.jl:8
 [2] top-level scope at none:1
```

Note that I used the absolute path in the `include(...)` to avoid using `LOAD_PATH` stuff, and added `.` before the module name (i.e., `using .myMoldule`).

What seems to be the problem?

P.S.: Julia version information:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.5.2
Commit 539f3ce943 (2020-09-23 23:17 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-9.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
Environment:
  JULIA_DEPOT_PATH = C:\Users\f\.julia;C:\opt\JuliaPro-1.5.2-1\Julia-1.5.2\local\share\julia;C:\opt\JuliaPro-1.5.2-1\Julia-1.5.2\share\julia
  JULIA_LOAD_PATH = @;@v#.#;@stdlib
  JULIA_NUM_THREADS = 6
  JULIA_PKG_SERVER = pkg.juliahub.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Corrections to be made:

- `sum` is a function in `Base` you should use a different name
- no need to declare `sum` variable (and it should be named something like `mysum`)
- Remove space before `::`
- Module names should start with a CapitalLetter
- You have a typo in module name perhaps you are loading a different module than you think?

Once corrected your code works.

Comment: I fixed all the issues pointed out by Przemyslaw Szufel. I found it's not the way I named `sum` or module that leads to the `UndefVarError: Param not defined` error.

Comment: A minor note of clarification for the readers, spaces are allowed around `::` and can be nice for readability when defining `structs`. :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue happens because you are using `.MyModule1`, not in the `MyModule2`, and thus you import `Param` to the Main module but not to the `MyModule2`, thus Module2 does not see `Param`.

If you will put `using ..MyModule1` (two dots instead of one as you there is one more level) into `MyModule2` this issue will go.

However, your code still will not work, since julia's `include` function just runs all the content of the included file, thus even you included the same file, you will create different instances of the modules. This warning `WARNING: replacing module...` indicates that somewhere in your code you might use the different version of the module (in you case, Main.Module1 and Main.Module2.Module1).

The common practice in julia is to include all the files in one place (they should be included only once). For instance, you can put all the includes in the file `useModule.jl`:

```
include("./defineModule1.jl")
include("./defineModule2.jl")
using .MyModule1
using .MyModule2

function testModule()

    param = Param(1, 2)

    # call myAdd to get the sum of param.x and param.y
    sumValue = myAdd(param)
    println(sumValue)

    # call mySubtract to get the difference of param.x and param.y
    difValue = mySubtract(param)
    println(difValue)
    
end
```

Do not include files in other places. e.g.
`defineModule2.jl` content:

```
module MyModule2

    using ..MyModule1

    export myAdd, mySubtract

    function myAdd(param::Param)
        return param.x + param.y
    end

    function mySubtract(param::Param)
        return param.x - param.y
    end

end # end of module
```

Answer (score 2):

**Questioner's note**: The following new question voted downwards (perhaps) was extended form the original one and was well answered by **Vitaliy Yakovchuk**.

---

I fixed all the issues pointed out by Przemyslaw Szufel. In my case above, it's not the improper ways of naming that cause the issue.

Now, I have a better exmaple to clarify my issue.

Suppose that, to meet the needs, I have to seperate my julia source code into two modules, e.g., define of a mutable struct `Param` in `defineModule1.jl` and define of functions in `defineModule2.jl`. The code scripts are as follows:

1. `"D:\\run\\defineModule1.jl"`:

```
module MyModule1

    export Param

    mutable struct Param
        x::Int64
        y::Int64
    end

end # end of module
```

2. `"D:\\run\\defineModule2.jl"`:

```
include("D:\\run\\defineModule1.jl"); using .MyModule1

module MyModule2

    export myAdd, mySubtract

    function myAdd(param::Param)
        return param.x + param.y
    end

    function mySubtract(param::Param)
        return param.x - param.y
    end

end # end of module
```

Note that `Param` is not defined here, and to make `Param` available, a line `include("D:\\run\\defineModule1.jl"); using .MyModule1` is added as the first line of this file.

3. `"D:\\run\\useModule.jl"`:

```
include("D:\\run\\defineModule1.jl"); using .MyModule1
include("D:\\run\\defineModule2.jl"); using .MyModule2

function testModule()

    param = Param(1, 2)

    # call myAdd to get the sum of param.x and param.y
    sumValue = myAdd(param)
    println(sumValue)

    # call mySubtract to get the difference of param.x and param.y
    difValue = mySubtract(param)
    println(difValue)
    
end
```

Note that both function `myAdd(param)` and `mySubtract(param)` in the script `defineModule2.jl` need the predefined mutable struct `Param` in `defineModule1.jl`.

This is what I got when I run `D:\\run\\useModule.jl`:

```
julia> include("D:\\run\\useModule.jl")
WARNING: replacing module MyModule1.
WARNING: replacing module MyModule1.
WARNING: replacing module MyModule2.
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: Param not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at D:\run\defineModule2.jl:7
 [2] include(::String) at .\client.jl:457
 [3] top-level scope at D:\run\useModule.jl:2
 [4] include(::String) at .\client.jl:457
 [5] top-level scope at none:1
in expression starting at D:\run\defineModule2.jl:7
in expression starting at D:\run\useModule.jl:2
```

I believed that, by using the following lines in the beginning of "D:\run\useModule.jl", the mutable struct `Param` should have be found:

```
include("D:\\run\\defineModule1.jl"); using .MyModule1
include("D:\\run\\defineModule2.jl"); using .MyModule2
...
```

Still, error `LoadError: UndefVarError: Param not defined` is reported.

So, Why can't `Param` be found by `D:\\run\\useModule.jl`?